# Query column from data where IS NOT NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to filter a mySQL database table into a web page. I am okay when it comes to getting specific data from a column using the query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM availability WHERE location = 'London'");
```

But what I am having particular trouble with is retrieving results from a column where there are some variable values as well as some NULL values. I just can't get it to work. What I want to do is select the table, identify a column and then display all results from that specific column where there is a value i.e. not null. At present I have tried things like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM availability WHERE team IS NOT NULL")

$result = mysql_query("SELECT team FROM availability WHERE team IS NOT NULL");
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not an expert with PHP and have researched and tried various solutions but I keep getting a server error. Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: What "server error" do you get?

Comment: Your query seems fine.

Comment: ``SELECT * FROM availability WHERE location='London' OR location IS NULL``, maybe?

Comment: please try this $result = mysql_query("SELECT `team` FROM availability WHERE `team` IS NOT NULL");
You query worked fine. i think try to use "`" before and after field name. hope it help.

Comment: Error: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Can you debug the web server itself and find out why he failed?  A 500 error just means "something bad happened on the web server".  You need to find out what happened.

Comment: All sorted. Was actually missing a ; a few lines up before a line I commented out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a semicolon between the first and the second row:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM availability WHERE team IS NOT NULL");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT team FROM availability WHERE team IS NOT NULL");
```

And I guess you don't want to name both variables as `$result`.

PS: You should use MySQLi or PDO instead of `mysql_*` functions, which are deprecated. [More information avalible here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Where did he forget a `;`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat the first line

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Between the first and the second row.

Comment: AH!  I didn't notice that was missing from the question~

Comment: To be honest guys, shame on me but in a line before anything I showed on here I was missing a ;. SELECT * FROM availability WHERE team IS NOT NULL works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You did the right sql.
The right sql should be:

```
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT `team` FROM `availability` WHERE `team` IS NOT NULL");
```

then only show the value those are not null. You just check you are using the right field in where condition..